# MYSQL Advanced select distinct values with corresponding ID which are not in anothe table

Tags: mysql, distinct

EDITED:

I have a huge problem with `SELECT` `DISTINCT` values from one of my table.

Table 1 :`T1`

```
pid      thing       sub-thing     tnumber     
-------------------------------------------
1       A1212       A01A00001     123456      
2       A1212       A01A00002     123457     
3       A1212       A01A00002     123458      
4       A1214       A01B00001     123459     
5       A1214       A01B00002     123460        
6       A1214       A01B00001     123461         
7       A1217       C01A00001     123462
```

Table 2 :`T2`

```
id        pid      thing       sub-thing         tnumber    h1 
-------------------------------------------------------------- 
1          3            A1212       A01A00002     123458   False
```

I need to `SELECT` all `DISTINCT` sub-things for every thing from Table `T1` which are NOT in Table `T2` and, most important - only sub-thing with the highest tnumber (for ex. with max(id)).

Result Should leave records 2, 4 from `T1` because there are identical sub-things with higher tnumber and of course leave record 3 from `T1` because it's in the `T2`.
Final result should be like this

```
id      thing       sub-thing     tnumber     
-------------------------------------------
1       A1212       A01A00001     123456                 
5       A1214       A01B00002     123460        
6       A1214       A01B00001     123461         
7       A1217       C01A00001     123462
```

Thanks to everyone here, the syntax I've tried is:

```
SELECT DISTINCT t1.pid, t1.thing, t1.subthing, t1.tnumber 
FROM t1 INNER JOIN
(SELECT t1.thing, t1.subthing, max(t1.tnumber) as tnumber FROM t1 LEFT OUTER JOIN t2 o ON t1.pid=o.pid WHERE o.pid IS NULL
AND t1.added>'2015-10-31' 
GROUP BY t1.subthing, thing) 
as b using (subthing, thing, tnumber) ;
```

Now I need to add a condition that the records from `T1` where `T1.pid` is NOT in `T2.pid` AND `t2.h1=false` should NOT be given in final result.

Comment: i didnt get why 2,4 left out.. Their `sub-thing` is not IDENTICAL

Comment: Because there are already identical sub things (id 3/6) with higher tnumber

Answer (score 2):

This query will return the MAX(id) for every subthing:

```
SELECT subthing, MAX(id) AS max_id
FROM t1
WHERE subthing NOT IN (SELECT subthing FROM t2) 
GROUP BY subthing;
```

(i think that you want to exclude all subthings that are present in t2)

Then with this query you can retrieve all the other columns for the maximum id:

```
SELECT t1.*
FROM t1
WHERE ID IN (
    SELECT MAX(id) AS max_id
    FROM t1
    WHERE subthing NOT IN (SELECT subthing FROM t2) 
    GROUP BY subthing
  )
```

Please see a fiddle [here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/b2be2/2). If yow want better performances, you could try with a LEFT JOIN:

```
SELECT ta.*
FROM
  t1 AS ta LEFT JOIN t1 AS tb
  ON ta.subthing=tb.subthing
     AND ta.id<tb.id
WHERE
  ta.subthing NOT IN (SELECT subthing FROM t2)
  AND tb.id IS NULL
```

(please make sure that t1.id is indexed, and also an index on subthing on both tables should help).

Comment: id are always indexed, so t1.id will be.

Comment: @fthiella,  thanx for help. It looks correct. I just need to test it on my local database. Give me a while :)

Is Left Join really faster than subquery?

Comment: Worked Almost OK - didn't leave some records when identical sub-thing was more than 2.

Comment: @PapaRazzo left join is not always faster than a subquery, but mysql can often optimize it better. what do you mean with "identical sub-thing more than 2"?

Comment: @MateoBarahona not necessarily, on my fiddle they are not indexed :)

Comment: @PapaRazzo do you have some null subthing in your t2 table? NOT IN is not always happy with null values

Comment: @ fthiella , i mean in T1 there are for ex 2 or more identical sub-things for one thing with unique `tnumber`. Now i don't have any nulls in T2 but I'm must consider it for future.

Answer (score 1):

try left outer join:

```
    select distinct t1.id, t1.thing, t1.subthing, t1.tnumber from t1 inner join (SELECT t1.thing, subthing, max(t1.tnumber) as tnumber 
FROM t1 left outer join t2 using (subthing) where t2.subthing is NULL GROUP BY subthing, thing) as b using (subthing, thing, tnumber) ;
```

create a concatenated Index:

```
create index index_name t1(subthing, thing, tnumber);
```

Comment: That creates the proper result !

Comment: Even if there is many duplicated sub-things for one thing (of course with unique tnumber) result is proper. Thanks man!

Comment: Found One issue with ID - please see my answer

Comment: Looks pretty Good. Works even if  fo ex. t1/t2 `thing` value are null

Comment: According to Your syntax, it's based on comparision of sub-things in T1/T2 tables.
Is it possible to compare/join   `T1` vs `T2` using `T1.id` and `T2.id_table_t1` (where there is no T1.id in T2.id_table_t1)? 
I mean -  no matter what values are in `T2.Thing`, `T2.sub-thing`, `T2.tnumber` if `T2.id_table_t1` doesn't have the value of `T1.id` then the `T1.id` record is correct and should be in final result.

Answer (score 0):

Try something like that ?

```
SELECT *
FROM T1
WHERE CONCAT_WS('-', thing, `sub-thing`, tnumber) IN
(SELECT CONCAT_WS('-', thing, `sub-thing`, max_tnumber)
FROM (
    SELECT MAX(tnumber) AS max_tnumber, thing, `sub-thing`
    FROM T1
    WHERE T1.`sub-thing` NOT IN (SELECT `sub-thing` FROM T2)
    GROUP BY thing, `sub-thing`
) as view
);
```

Answer (score 0):

I Found One issue in following LFJ syntax:

```
SELECT t1.id, t1.thing, subthing, max(t1.tnumber) as tnumber
FROM t1 left outer join t2 using (subthing) where t2.subthing is NULL GROUP BY subthing, thing;
```

will result

```
4       A1214       A01B00001     123459
```

in stead of

```
6       A1214       A01B00001     123461
```

id=4 is the first ID for that sub-thing but number 123461 is from the max tnumber but max tnumber is in record id=6.

I think syntax should start with:

```
SELECT max(t1.id), t1.thing (...)
```

Comment: Actually it's normal, you can't use that to do what you want, because you don't group by id and don't want to, so it will take some random id, not matching rest of the query.

Comment: And that's why I gave you a different approach, first, but I don't know if you even tried it...

Answer (score 0):

Some modification I've made based on @LFJ syntax.

```
'changed `t1.id` column to `t1.pid`'
'changed `t2.id_table_t1` column to `t2.pid`'
'and JOINed tables via `pid` columns'
SELECT DISTINCT t1.pid, t1.thing, t1.subthing, t1.tnumber 
FROM t1 INNER JOIN
(SELECT t1.thing, t1.subthing, max(t1.tnumber) as tnumber FROM t1 LEFT OUTER JOIN t2 o ON t1.pid=o.pid WHERE o.pid IS NULL
AND t1.added>'2015-10-31' 
GROUP BY t1.subthing, thing) 
as b using (subthing, thing, tnumber) ;
```

Result is the same but comparision is via `pid` column (old ID) , not `tnumber` column, which means even if in the `T2.tnumber` is whatever value the result will be the same :)

I think this is the end. Maybe it'll help somebody in future.
Thanks a lot.